# "I intend to cast my vote is person...." Meaning in this context

Tags: sentence-meaning

In an application to an officer:

> Sir,
>
> I intend to cast my vote is person at the ensuing election to the Legislative assembly.....

What's the meaning of "is person" in this context?

Thank you.

Comment: Probable error, "in person" not "is person".  If you think that this is a simple error, you might delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to perform some actions by completion of a form, letter, telephone, email, etc, or by being physically present at a place where the action can be done. This is described as doing the action **in**  person (not "is person").

[In person](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-person)